# Integrar Web API (petición XML) en Python

Tags: python, xml, api, rest

Necesito integrar una API web en Python para mandar SMS a un listado de clientes, pero no sé por dónde empezar, ya que soy novata.

Dejo un ejemplo que dan los de la API para ver si me podéis decir cómo adaptarlo en Python (es para hacer ping a la API):

```
POST https://sms.didimo.es/wcf/Service.svc/rest/Ping HTTP/1.1

<PingRequest xmlns="https://sms.didimo.es/wcf/PingRequest">
  <UserName>{:UserName}</UserName>
  <”>{:Password}</Password>
</PingRequest>

Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
```

Esto es lo que he probado, pero no funciona:

```
payload = {"UserName":"myusername", "Password":"mypassword"}

solicitud = requests.post("https://sms.didimo.es/wcf/Service.svc/rest/Ping", params = payload)

if solicitud.status_code == 200:
 print(solicitud.text)

if solicitud.status_code == 200:
    print(solicitud.text)
else: 
  print("Error")
  print(solicitud.status_code)
```

[Este es el link de ayuda](https://sms.didimo.es/wcf/Service.svc/rest/help/operations/Ping) que dan ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que intentas pasar los datos del diccionario como parámetros de la petición directamente, cuando lo que debes enviar a la petición, según la documentación de la API, es un XML o un JSON que básicamente contienen los datos de autentificación en este caso.

- **Para usar un JSON** basta con utilizar el argumento `json` de `requests.post` y pasarle directamente el diccionario:

  ```
  import requests


  url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
  payload = {'some': 'data'}


  url = "https://sms.didimo.es/wcf/Service.svc/rest/Ping"
  sol_json = {"UserName":"myusername",
              "Password":"mypassword"
              }
  solicitud = requests.post(url, json=sol_json)

  if solicitud.status_code == 200:
      print(solicitud.text)
  else: 
      print("Error")
      print(solicitud.status_code)
  ```

  Alternativamente (y en versiones antiguas de `requets`) puedes hacer:

  ```
  import json
  import requests



  url = "https://sms.didimo.es/wcf/Service.svc/rest/Ping"
  sol_json = {"UserName":"myusername",
              "Password":"mypassword"
              }
  solicitud = requests.post(url,
                            data=json.dumps(sol_json),
                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                            )

  if solicitud.status_code == 200:
      print(solicitud.text)
  else: 
      print("Error")
  print(solicitud.status_code)
  ```

  En este caso debes usar el argumento `data` para agregar el JSON (en texto como tal, `str`) y especificarle al servidor mediante las cabeceras que le estás enviando un JSON.
- **Para usar XML** se hace igual que en el último ejemplo con JSON, solo debes modificar las cabeceras apropiadamente:

  ```
  import requests


  url = "https://sms.didimo.es/wcf/Service.svc/rest/Ping"
  user = "MyUser"
  password = "MyPassword"

  sol_xml = f"""
  <PingRequest xmlns="https://sms.didimo.es/wcf/PingRequest">
    <UserName>{user}</UserName>
    <Password>{password}</Password>
  </PingRequest>
  """

  solicitud = requests.post(url,
                            data=sol_xml,
                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
                            )

  if solicitud.status_code == 200:
      print(solicitud.text)
  else: 
      print("Error")
      print(solicitud.status_code)
  ```

Usa JSON si te dan ambas opciones, es más ameno como puede verse.

Comment: Mil gracias, ha funcionado perfectamente!! Ahora a probar cosas más avanzadas siguiendo tu ejemplo.